# How to force Lotus Notes client to use "Internet mail address" setting in Location properties as "From" and "Reply To" field when using SMTP?

Tags: smtp, lotus-notes

I previously worked in a company where we used Lotus Notes (8.5.3) for mail and other shared databases. Now our team became a Distributor of that company, and the full functionality of Lotus Notes was reduced for us - we don't have mail, but still use some corporate databases for everyday work. I want to integrate my new mail into Notes client - so I've created two accounts for incoming (IMAP online) and outgoing (SMTP) mail.

In old company we had emails like Name_Surname@Oldcompany.com, and in Notes address fields they displayed as Name Surname/Oldcompany

My new email is Name.Surname@Newcompany.com

I've edited location 'Online', put Name.Surname@Newcompany.com in the Internet mail address, in Mail tab Domino mail domain = Newcompany.com, Send outgoing mail = Directly to Internet.

I'm able to receive and send mail but the problem is:

When recipient receives an E-mail sent by me through Notes - From and Reply To fields are like: Name_Surname/Oldcompany@Newcompany.com

How can I fix this and set Notes client to use Internet mail address (Name.Surname@Newcompany.com)?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I used mail.nsf file from old company (when configuring IMAP) and there was Mail - More - Preferences - Owner setting set to Name Surname/Oldcompany. I've changed owner to Name.Surname@Newcompany.com and problem with incorrect 'From' field has gone!